# Getting regex from file and applying it on different python file

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have lot of regex to work on particular huge data and it is working now but the number of regex is growing day by day.

so i had planned to move the regex out of main python into a text or a cnf file, but when getting regex from another file and applying it on data doesnt give the correct output which i was getting earlier when both are in same file.

kindly give some pointers on this.

Comment: A minimal example of your code would help a lot finding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine for me:

```
open('regex.txt', 'w').write(r'(\d+)\s*(\w+)')
open('text.txt', 'w').write('foo 21   bar')


import re
regex = open('regex.txt').read()
text = open('text.txt').read()
print(re.findall(regex, text)) # [('21', 'bar')]
```

Make sure you are:

- Ignoring trailing whitespace on the regex file (like line endings, otherwise the engine will try to match that too). You can use `re.findall(regex, text.strip())` for that.
- Escaping values properly (note I used `r''` instead of just `''`, so the backslashes would be written correctly). Have you visually inspected the file to make sure it has no duplicated backslashes, for example?
- Reading the correct files (stupid mistake we make all the time).